# Custom route constraint causes intermittent 404 errors

Tags: thread-safety, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-1.0, route-constraint

I have an `Asp.Net Core 1 RC1` application that uses a custom route constraint to control access to the application. The application (hosted on a server running `IIS 7.5`) is getting intermittent 404 errors which I suspect is caused by this routing constraint. Here you can see a screenshot that shows the intermittent 404 errors:

[image]

I suspect that this issue is related to the code that defines the route constraint not being thread-safe. The custom route constraint needs a `DbContext` because it needs to check in the database if the application is enabled for the brand specified in the route, and I suspect that this `DbContext` instance could be causing the issue. Here is how the routing is defined in the application:

```
// Add MVC to the request pipeline.
var appDbContext = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "branding",
        template: "branding/{brand}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index" },
        constraints: new { brand = new BrandingRouteConstraint(appDbContext) });
});
```

And here is the custom route constraint:

```
// Custom route constraint
public class BrandingRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    AppDbContext _appDbContext;
    public BrandingRouteConstraint(AppDbContext appDbContext) : base() {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, IDictionary<string, object> values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values.Keys.Contains(routeKey))
        {
            var whiteLabel = _appDbContext.WhiteLabels.Where(w => w.Url == values[routeKey].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (whiteLabel != null && whiteLabel.EnableApplication != null && (bool)whiteLabel.EnableApplication)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone confirm that this issue is caused by the code not being thread-safe and recommend a way to change the implementation so that it is thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on RouteContraint's, haven't used them much, but have you tried Resource Based Authorization instead? Looks like it might be more suited to what you're trying to achieve?

From [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html) and [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/):

Request authentication service inside your controller

```
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    IAuthorizationService authorizationService;

    public DocumentController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }
}
```

Apply authorization checks in your Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid documentId)
{
    Document document = documentRepository.Find(documentId);

    if (document == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    if (await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, document, Operations.Edit))
    {
        return View(document);
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

I've used the OperationAuthorizationRequirement class in the sample, so define this class in your project:

```
public static class Operations
{
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Create =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Create" };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Read =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Read" };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Update =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Update" };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Delete =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Delete" };
}
```

Implement the authorization handler (using built in OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement):

```
public class DocumentAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Document>
{
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context,
                                   OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
                                   Document resource)
    {
        // Validate the requirement against the resource and identity.
        // Sample just checks "Name"field, put your real logic here :)
        if (resource.Name == "Doc1")
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        else
            context.Fail();
    }
}
```

And not forgetting ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddInstance<IAuthorizationHandler>(
    new DocumentAuthorizationHandler());
```

It's a bit more work, but adds quite a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Hi Greg. Thanks for the answer. I did manage to resolve the thread-safety issue by removing the instantiation of the `DbContext` from the start and include it rather in the code for the route constraint.  I never knew about this Resource Based Authentication that you outline here and it does seem like a better fit for what I am trying to achieve. So thanks for the help. :)